# Awk se ejecuta en consola pero cuanto lo meto a un archivo .sh da error

Tags: bash

El script sirve par insertar informacion a mariadb, mi base de datos se llama "Top" y mi tabla se llama "Procesos", los campos que estoy llenando son

```
(User, Pid,  Cpu, Mem, Vsz, Rss, Tty, Stat, Start, Time, Command)
```

con los valores que están en el archivo "texto.txt".

```
elias@elias-VirtualBox:~$ mysql -u root -p Top < <(awk '/ [0-11]+/ {print "INSERT INTO Procesos (User, Pid,  Cpu, Mem, Vsz, Rss, Tty, Stat, Start, Time, Command) VALUES (\""$1"\", \""$2"\", \""$3"\", \""$4"\", \""$5"\", \""$6"\", \""$7"\", \""$8"\", \""$9"\", \""$10"\", \""$11"\");"}' /var/www/html/texto.txt)
Enter password:
```

Después de ingresar la contraseña de la base de datos y revisarla, efectivamente se cargan los datos, el problema es que estoy tratando de automatizarlo y cuando lo ejecuto en un archivo .sh me da el siguiente error

```
elias@elias-VirtualBox:/var/www/html$ ./insert.sh
./insert.sh: línea 2: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `<'
./insert.sh: línea 2: `mysql -u root -p Top < <(awk '/ [0-11]+/ {print "INSERT 
INTO Procesos (User, Pid,  Cpu, Mem, Vsz, Rss, Tty, Stat, Start, Time, Command) VALUES (\""$1"\", \""$2"\", \""$3"\", \""$4"\", \""$5"\", \""$6"\", \""$7"\", \""$8"\", \""$9"\", \""$10"\", \""$11"\");"}' /var/www/html/texto.txt)'
```

El contenido del insert.sh es:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -u root -p Top < <(awk '/ [0-11]+/ {print "INSERT INTO Procesos (User, Pid,  Cpu, Mem, Vsz, Rss, Tty, Stat, Start, Time, Command) VALUES (\""$1"\", \""$2"\", \""$3"\", \""$4"\", \""$5"\", \""$6"\", \""$7"\", \""$8"\", \""$9"\", \""$10"\", \""$11"\");"}' /var/www/html/texto.txt)
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

P.D.: Estoy usando  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido del archivo "insert.sh", o al menos el contenido problemático?

Comment: #!/bin/sh
mysql -u root -p Top < <(awk '/ [0-11]+/ {print "INSERT INTO Procesos (User, Pid,  Cpu, Mem, Vsz, Rss, Tty, Stat, Start, Time, Command) VALUES (\""$1"\", \""$2"\", \""$3"\", \""$4"\", \""$5"\", \""$6"\", \""$7"\", \""$8"\", \""$9"\", \""$10"\", \""$11"\");"}' /var/www/html/texto.txt)

Answer (score 1):

El problema era que el encabezado del "insert.sh" estaba mal redactado.
El encabezado correcto era este:

```
#!/bin/bash
```